# Resize a div with position:relative pushes other divs

Tags: html, firefox, browser, resize, drag

I'm trying to resize a draggable div that holds an IMG and everytime I do it pushes the other div aside. If I change the position to absolute the div doesn't drag smoothly and jumps away from the mouse.

```
<div id="div1" class="draggable">
<div class="resizable">
<img alt="".           src="https://upload.Wikipedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Smiley_icon.png" />
</div>
</div>

<div id="div2" class="draggable">
<div class="resizable">
<img alt=""      src="https://upload.Wikipedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Smiley_icon.png" />
</div>
</div>

<style>
.draggable{
position:relative; 
cursor:pointer;
}
.resizable{
{
width:100px;
border:1px;
}
.resizable img {
width:100%;
}
.ui-resizable-handle {
background: #f5dc58;
border:1px;
width:5px;
height:5px;
z-index: 2;
}
.ui-resizable-se {
right: -5px;
bottom: -5px;
}
</style>

<script>
$('.draggable').draggable();

$('.resizable').resizable({
aspectRatio:true,
handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw'
});

</script>
```

Comment: You need to provide a bit more information to get help answering the question, I assume this is taking place in a browser? If so, what is the name/version. More information about your dev environment will get you more help because 2 sentences is usually not enough context.

Comment: I've provided the code I'm using in a Kuno Creative Group Firefox (it's what I was given to work with)

Comment: I'd make it easier for potential question replies and instead of showing us just the div tags, post the entire webpage or (even better) post the test case (a truncated version of the entire web page that can be loaded into the browser to demonstrate your problem). Most people aren't going to take the time to type in HTML tags, etc... to make your example work.